# Linux: write a C program that 'controls' a shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, controls

Suppose we have a shell running on terminal, let's say, /dev/pts/1.  The shell is already running and we can't restart it.

Now we want to write a C program that will 'control' the shell, i.e. which will itself provide a shell-like interface to the user, read user's input, pass it on to the real shell on /dev/pts/1, have it execute it, read shell's output and print it back to the user.

I know how to do half of this task: I know how to gather user's input and inject this input to the 'real shell' :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if( argc>1 )
  {
  int tty = open( argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);

  if( tty!=-1 )
    {
    char *buf,buffer[SIZE+1];

    while(1)
      {
      printf("> ");
      fgets( buffer, SIZE, stdin );
      if( buffer[0]=='q' && buffer[1]=='u' && buffer[2]=='i' && buffer[3]=='t' ) break;
      for(buf=buffer; *buf!='\0'; buf++ ) ioctl(tty, TIOCSTI, buf);
      }

    close(tty);
    }
  else printf("Failed to open terminal %s\n", argv[1]);
  }

return 0;
}
```

The above will pass on your input to shell running in terminal ( give its name in the first argument ) and have the shell execute it. However, I don't know how to read the shell's output now.

Any tips?

Comment: Did you try reading from the tty ?

Comment: Is this homework or rootkit?

Comment: @Kimvais In its current format, you'd have to execute this program to pass the commands through this shell-on-shell - you'd have to do a lot more than simply control a shell to write a rootkit.

Comment: Why are you reimplementing Expect?

Comment: @kimvais: here's a longer description of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746018/linux-capture-output-of-an-already-running-process-in-pure-c Basically, I am trying to remotely control a bunch of gizmos :) @alexandre: how do I read from a TTY?

Comment: @Leszek: the same way you read from a normal file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want to start reading from the other shell's controlling tty _before_ you talk to ioctl.

Comment: @ glenn: 'expect' has it easy, because it can spawn the shell it is going to control and thus can use pty_copy to put itself between the shell and its controlling terminal - something I cannot do as the shell is already running. ( read Stevens, 'Advanced Programming in Unix Environment' section 19.5 for description how expect works )

Comment: @Ninefingers, well if one was to build a rootkit, probably the simplest way to hide the rootkit from an _unsuspecting_ user would be to hijack the shell and filter the output of commands like 'ps ax' and 'ls' instead of replacing all the binaries...

Comment: @Kimvais Maybe he works for a law enforcement agency that needs a rootkit to spy on Mexican drug gangs (who run slowaris). I don't think we should judge. There are much more efficient ways to do a rootkit or man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pipes](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Programming-with-pipes.html) for that. Linux shells allow redirection.

I used pipes to control tty's.

Answer (score 2):

please take a look at [libpipeline](http://libpipeline.nongnu.org). maybe this will help you...

Answer (score 2):

There are programs that allow you to change the controlling terminal for a process: [reptyr](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/) and [injcode](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2009/03/Moving-a-process-to-another-terminal) are two such programs.

I do believe that they sever the other terminal, however, so depending on your needs this may or may not fit exactly.